# Undefined symbolエラーによりFlutterからSwiftの画面が開けない

Tags: swift, flutter

FlutterからSwiftの画面を開きたいのですが、Undefined symbolエラーが発生して開けません。
Swift 画面で FirebaseAnalytics を使用しています。

```
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC0D16DecodingStrategyO6base64yA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC19KeyDecodingStrategyO14useDefaultKeysyA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC19keyDecodingStrategyAC03KeygH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC20DateDecodingStrategyO6customyAE10Foundation0F0Vs0E0_pKccAEmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC20dataDecodingStrategyAC0dgH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC20dateDecodingStrategyAC04DategH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC23passthroughTypeResolverAA026StructureCodingPassthroughgH0_pXpvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC34NonConformingFloatDecodingStrategyO5throwyA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC34nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategyAC03NonghiJ0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC6decode_4fromxxm_yptKSeRzlFTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataDecoderC8userInfoSDys010CodingUserG3KeyVypGvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC0D16EncodingStrategyO6base64yA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC19KeyEncodingStrategyO14useDefaultKeysyA2EmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC19keyEncodingStrategyAC03KeygH0OvsTj
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC20DateEncodingStrategyO6customyAEy10Foundation0F0V_s0E0_ptKccAEmFWC
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$s19FirebaseSharedSwift0A11DataEncoderC20dataEncodingStrategyAC0dgH0OvsTj
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebaseの依存関係を修正したら成功しました
10.0.0 → 9.6.0

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '9.6.0'
```

```
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.3
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.3
  firebase_analytics: ^9.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.2
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.8.6
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.3.3
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.4
  firebase_remote_config: ^2.0.13
```